# Wcf Rest Service Return Number Conversion Error

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Rest Service into Angular JS Application . I am trying to display single record based on account number in input filed. But when i click the submit button to display the record then i got following errors in Google Chrome Network Tap.

**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '{Account_Number}15' to data type int.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:**

And its returns 400 Bad Request on Post Method Operation .

Here is the interface .

```
 [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "/GetAccountDetails/{Account_Number}")]
        string  GetAccountDetails(string Account_Number);
```

Here is the Implementation.

```
 public string GetAccountDetails(string Account_Number)
        {
            List<object> customers = new List<object>();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Holder_Details WHERE Account_Number = @Account_Number";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", Account_Number);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {

                            customers.Add(new
                            {
                                Tittle = sdr["Tittle"],
                                Account_Holder_First_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_First_Name"],
                                Account_Holder_Last_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Last_Name"],
                                Account_Holder_DOB = sdr["Account_Holder_DOB"],
                                Account_Holder_House_No = sdr["Account_Holder_House_No"],
                                Account_Holder_Street_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Street_Name"],
                                Account_Holder_Post_Code = sdr["Account_Holder_Post_Code"],

                                Account_Holder_Occupation = sdr["Account_Holder_Occupation"],
                                Account_Number = sdr["Account_Number"]



                            });
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

                return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customers));
            }

        }
```

Here is the Script code.

```
var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])
    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
        var Account_Number = $scope.Account_Number;
        $scope.search = function (Account_Number) {
            var promisePostSingle = myService.postbyId(Account_Number);

        promisePostSingle.then(function (pl) {
            var res = pl.data;
            $scope.Account_Number = res.Account_Number;
            $scope.Account_Creation_Date = res.Account_Creation_Date;
            $scope.Account_Type = res.Account_Type;
            $scope.Branch_Sort_Code = res.Branch_Sort_Code;
            $scope.Account_Fees = res.Account_Fees;
            $scope.Account_Balance = res.Account_Balance;
            $scope.Over_Draft_Limit = res.Over_Draft_Limit;

            //   $scope.IsNewRecord = 0;
        },
            function (errorPl) {
                console.log('failure loading Employee', errorPl);
            });
    }
    }]);




app.service("myService", function ($http) {

    this.postbyId = function (Id) {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetAccountDetails/{Account_Number}" + Id);
    };
   })
```

Here is the HTML .

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="WebClientModule">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>AccountBalance</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/AccountBalance.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        Enter Account_Number: <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
        <input type="button"  value="search" ng-click="search(Account_Number)" />

            <table id="tblContainer">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Account Number</th>
                                <th>Account Creation Date</th>
                                <th>Account Type</th>
                                <th>Branch Sort Code</th>
                                <th>Account Fees</th>
                                <th>Account Balance</th>
                                <th>Over Draft Limit</th>

                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody data-ng-repeat="user in Users">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Number}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Creation_Date}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Type}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Branch_Sort_Code}}</span></td>

                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Fees}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Balance}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Over_Draft_Limit}}</span></td>
                                    <td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </body>


</html>
```

Here is the Screen Shot on Debugging mode on Wcf Service .
[image]

Here is the result on Google Chrome Console Windows .
[image]

Comment: your `$http.post` has one parameter (url, without data), shouldn't it be `$http.get` instead?

Comment: In url I already mentioned the parameters

Comment: Please check the script file code

Comment: with the wrong syntax then

Comment: Why this post was voted down . Is that questions is not clear ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it;

```
$http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetAccountDetails/{Account_Number}" + Id);
```

to

```
$http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetAccountDetails?Account_Number=" + Id);
```

You are sending the parameter as `{Account_Number}15`. It should be `15`.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: Shall I change the interface as well

Comment: It would be better to change POST to GET. Because you are not posting nothing to endpoint already.

Comment: I made the changes and i change the interface as well .Now i got error that service end point now found

Comment: if you say make that to GET . With the GET Request i can not pass the paramaters in interface method . What is the changes i have to make to get the correct result .

Comment: In console window 404 bad request

Comment: "$http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetAccountDetails?Account_Number=" + Id);" would you try like this.

Comment: In url there is no method name

Comment: Is with http post or get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160811/discussion-between-rainman-and-mohammad).

Comment: I will check it and will update you.  Thank you for the time

Comment: I am sorry to say that with you suggestion i did not get the expected result . With the POST Operation i got Error the end point and then i changes it to GET . Its showing the same Error as i described on the question . I really thnaks you for your time